# GHC Haskell performance of IPv4 address rendering

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-criterion

I recently built a library for handling IPv4 address in haskell. I have written two functions to render an `IPv4` address to `Text` and I am surprised that the naive approach outperforms the approach that I actually thought about. Here are the relevant pieces. First, there is the [definition of `IPv4`](https://github.com/andrewthad/haskell-ip/blob/9cc48ab7c39a44f01b9ef1a850f10d92bb6a859a/src/Net/IPv4.hs#L54):

```
newtype IPv4 = IPv4 { getIPv4 :: Word32 }
```

Next we have the [IP address renderer](https://github.com/andrewthad/haskell-ip/blob/9cc48ab7c39a44f01b9ef1a850f10d92bb6a859a/src/Net/IPv4.hs#L147) that I expected to perform well:

```
toDotDecimalText :: IPv4 -> Text
toDotDecimalText = LText.toStrict . TBuilder.toLazyText . toDotDecimalBuilder
{-# INLINE toDotDecimalText #-}

toDotDecimalBuilder :: IPv4 -> TBuilder.Builder
toDotDecimalBuilder (IPv4 w) = 
  decimal (255 .&. shiftR w 24 )
  <> dot
  <> decimal (255 .&. shiftR w 16 )
  <> dot
  <> decimal (255 .&. shiftR w 8 )
  <> dot
  <> decimal (255 .&. w)
  where dot = TBuilder.singleton '.'
{-# INLINE toDotDecimalBuilder #-}
```

Finally, we have the [naive implementation](https://github.com/andrewthad/haskell-ip/blob/9cc48ab7c39a44f01b9ef1a850f10d92bb6a859a/test/Naive.hs#L9):

```
ipv4ToTextNaive :: IPv4 -> Text
ipv4ToTextNaive i = Text.pack $ concat
  [ show a
  , "."
  , show b
  , "."
  , show c
  , "."
  , show d
  ]
  where (a,b,c,d) = IPv4.toOctets i
```

And finally, here is the [benchmark suite](https://github.com/andrewthad/haskell-ip/blob/9cc48ab7c39a44f01b9ef1a850f10d92bb6a859a/test/Bench.hs):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ipAddr = IPv4 1000000009
  defaultMain 
    [ bgroup "IPv4 to Text" 
      [ bench "Naive" $ whnf ipv4ToTextNaive ipAddr
      , bench "Current Implementation" $ whnf IPv4_Text.encode ipAddr
      ]
    ]
```

You can try this out by cloning the repository I've linked to and then running `stack bench --benchmark-arguments '--output=out.html'` in the top level directory of the project. The results I get are:

```
benchmarking IPv4 to Text/Naive
time                 391.1 ns   (389.9 ns .. 392.7 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 394.2 ns   (393.1 ns .. 396.4 ns)
std dev              4.989 ns   (2.990 ns .. 7.700 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 12% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking IPv4 to Text/Current Implementation
time                 467.5 ns   (466.0 ns .. 469.8 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 470.9 ns   (467.8 ns .. 478.3 ns)
std dev              14.75 ns   (8.245 ns .. 26.96 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 45% (moderately inflated)
```

The naive one (which uses `[Char]` and then packs it into `Text` at the end) beats the one I thought would do better (which uses a text `Builder`) every time.

I've consider several possibilities. One is that I've misused `criterion` or misunderstood weak head normal form for `Text`. Another is that a `Builder` doesn't perform like I thought it does. I always envisioned them as being like a difference list that was smarter about bitpacking, but from [the definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/src/Data-Text-Internal-Builder.html#Builder), I'm really not all that sure what I should expect.

Comment: My guess is that the builder approach has to create a lazy Text value first and then convert it to a strict Text. Things might be different if the builder had a toStrictText function.

Comment: Another impression I get from read the builder docs is that it seems to be designed to speed up the concatenation of lazy Text values to create a new lazy Text value.